# Navigating Webview on Swipe

Tags: android, webview

I have an Android Webview which shows webpages according to month. I would like users to be able to navigate between webpages by continuous swipe. For example currently is December, when user swipe left or right, the webpages of next or previous month will be showed. This is my code:

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                               float velocityY) {
            try {
                Values values = new Values(getApplicationContext());
                HashMap<String, Integer> valuesForSwipe = values
                        .getValuesForSwipe();
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > valuesForSwipe.get("swipeMaxOffPath"))
                    return false;
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > valuesForSwipe.get("swipeMinDistance")
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > valuesForSwipe.get("swipeThresholdVelocity")) {
                    if (webUrl.equals("file:///android_asset/dec.html")) {
                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/jan.html");
                        return true;    
                    }
                    if (webUrl.equals("file:///android_asset/jan.html")) {
                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/feb.html");
                        return true;
                    }
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > valuesForSwipe.get("swipeMinDistance")
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > valuesForSwipe.get("swipeThresholdVelocity")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), webView.getUrl(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Using the above code, for current month is Dec, the file `file:///android_asset/dec.html` is showed, when I swipe to the left, it seem to be worked and the page changed to jan.html. However, when I swipe to the left for second time, the page won't change to feb.html. Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: why don't you use `ViewPager`?

Comment: As a self-learner and I only heard about `ViewPager` until you mentioned it. But my current method is almost get what I intended. How can I get it to work using my method?